# How to repeat passages in Falk's №1?

Tags: guitar, coda, repeats

I'm trying to play R. Falk's №1. I don't understand how repetition works here with multiple coda signs/brackets. Could someone give me a hint? The music goes like this:

[image: Score of Rainer Falks's No. 1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your chart with bar numbers in blue and important landmarks highlighted in yellow:

[image]

This chart has repeat signs, repeat endings, two D.S. (Dal segno) and three coda signs. Here is how they work:

1. Start at the beginning and play through bar 8 (the first ending with repeat sign) Go back to bar 1 (repeat sign) and continue.
2. Play bar 1-7, skip bar 8, play bar 9 (to second ending) and continue.
3. Play through bar 18 (first ending) then repeat back to bar 11. Play again but skip bar 18 (to second ending) and play bar 19.
4. At this point it says D.S. to coda 1 so you go back (D.S.) to bar 1
5. Repeat step 1
6. Play bar 1-7, skip bar 8, play bar 9 (second ending) and then jump to bar 20 (coda to coda 1)
7. Play bars 20-37 then jump back to bar 1 (D.S. al coda 2)
8. Same as before, play 1-8 then 1-9 skipping bar 8 then after bar 9 jump to bar 38 (coda to coda 2) and play to the end.

That’s it!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler, and possibly clearer explanation:

- Play from the beginning (with repeats) until you get to the D.S.
- play from the segno sign  (repeats are optional) jumping from the coda  sign to coda 1
- play coda 1 until you get to the second D.S
- play from the segno sign (repeats still optional) jumping from the coda sign to coda 2
- play coda 2

The repeat brackets are played like this:
[image]